# eclipse hibernate plugin

Tags: hibernate, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-tools

Can somebody guide me how to install Hibernate tools in Eclipse. I am using Eclipse 3.3 ( I can upgrade to 3.4). I can use Hibernate 3.0 or 2.0.

I am not able to install the plugin. Its not getting detected. The update site gives error saying that WTP is required. When I try to install that, it again give some dependency error EFt etc.

I am going crazy, isn't there one package install for all this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I always do, and it works for me:

1. Get the java ee version of Eclipse, yes I would get 3.4 [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/ganymede/SR2/eclipse-jee-ganymede-SR2-win32.zip).
2. Install the Hibernate plugin [here](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/).

It does say on the hibernate tools page: 
"Requirements:   Eclipse WTP 3.4 or Ant, Decent driver and database"

So I might guess that 3.3 is what is causing your issues. Good luck!

Comment: AWESOME DUDE... THANKS ..that was pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

In case you decide to go for Eclipse Juno (v4.0) then go for JBoss Tools. Hibernate Tools plugin is now a part of JBoss Tools plugin. So, if you install JBoss Tools plugin then you automatically get Hibernate Tools plugin.

After installing Eclipse Juno open the Eclipse Marketplace window and search for "JBoss Tools" and then click on install button. Once the installation is over you will be prompted for a restart of Eclipse and you are done...

This link has a detailed pictorial on installing JBoss Tools plugin just in case you need it... http://www.javabrahman.com/j2ee/how-to-install-jboss-tools-eclipse-plugin/